# Deadlock in System.Component.TypeDescriptor

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-4, deadlock, typedescriptor

I have spent a lot of time (googling, reflecting .net binaries, etc) trying to resolve the following problem:

I see a deadlock in our application (ASP.NET MVC + EF4). We have several EF's contexts which are created at the beginning of the request and are disposed of at the end. Sometimes we have the following situation: ASP.NET creates a thread per request and then thread enters an "in join or sleep" state when accessing EF context.

Majority of the deadlocked threads have a stack trace as follows:

```
    System.dll!System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.Refresh(object component, bool refreshReflectionProvider) + 0x97 bytes    
    System.Data.dll!System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.DesignTimeVisible.set(bool value) + 0x22 bytes    
    System.Data.dll!System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.SqlCommand(System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand from) + 0xc9 bytes    
    System.Data.dll!System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.Clone() + 0x27 bytes    
    System.Data.dll!System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.System.ICloneable.Clone() + 0x9 bytes    
    System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.Common.DbCommandDefinition.CreateCommandDefinition(System.Data.Common.DbCommand prototype) + 0x47 bytes    
    System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.SqlClient.SqlProviderServices.CreateDbCommandDefinition(System.Data.Common.DbProviderManifest providerManifest, System.Data.Common.CommandTrees.DbCommandTree commandTree) + 0x21 bytes    
    System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.EntityClient.EntityCommandDefinition.EntityCommandDefinition(System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactory storeProviderFactory, System.Data.Common.CommandTrees.DbCommandTree commandTree) + 0x2a1 bytes    
    System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.EntityClient.EntityProviderServices.CreateDbCommandDefinition(System.Data.Common.DbProviderManifest providerManifest, System.Data.Common.CommandTrees.DbCommandTree commandTree) + 0x8e bytes    
    System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.Prepare(System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext context, System.Data.Common.CommandTrees.DbQueryCommandTree tree, System.Type elementType, System.Data.Objects.MergeOption mergeOption, System.Data.Objects.Span span, System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<System.Data.Objects.ObjectParameter,System.Data.Objects.ELinq.QueryParameterExpression>> compiledQueryParameters) + 0x113 bytes    
    System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ELinqQueryState.GetExecutionPlan(System.Data.Objects.MergeOption? forMergeOption) + 0x310 bytes    
    System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery<CompuTool.Business.Portal.Desktop>.GetResults(System.Data.Objects.MergeOption? forMergeOption) + 0x55 bytes    
    System.Data.Entity.dll!System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery<System.__Canon>.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator() + 0x2f bytes    
    System.Core.dll!System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault<CompuTool.Business.Portal.Desktop>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<CompuTool.Business.Portal.Desktop> source) + 0x10f bytes    
    System.Core.dll!System.Linq.Queryable.SingleOrDefault<CompuTool.Business.Portal.Desktop>(System.Linq.IQueryable<CompuTool.Business.Portal.Desktop> source, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<CompuTool.Business.Portal.Desktop,bool>> predicate) + 0x24e bytes    
>    CompuTool.Presentation.Web.dll!CompuTool.Presentation.Web.Controllers.DesktopStateController.ValidateRequest(CompuTool.Business.Portal.DesktopManagerContext dataContext, CompuTool.Business.Portal.User user, int desktopId) Line 30 + 0x19e bytes    C#
    CompuTool.Presentation.Web.dll!CompuTool.Presentation.Web.Controllers.DesktopStateController.SetDesktopState(CompuTool.Business.Portal.User user, int desktopId, string value) Line 65 + 0x17 bytes    C#
    CompuTool.Presentation.Web.dll!CompuTool.Presentation.Web.Controllers.DesktopStateController.Set(int desktopId, string value) Line 111 + 0x13 bytes    C#
    [Lightweight Function]    
    System.Web.Mvc.dll!System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext controllerContext, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string,object> parameters) + 0x108 bytes    
    System.Web.Mvc.dll!System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext controllerContext, System.Web.Mvc.ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string,object> parameters) + 0x27 bytes    
    System.Web.Mvc.dll!System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters.AnonymousMethod__12() + 0x81 bytes    
    System.Web.Mvc.dll!System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(System.Web.Mvc.IActionFilter filter, System.Web.Mvc.ActionExecutingContext preContext, System.Func<System.Web.Mvc.ActionExecutedContext> continuation) + 0xe6 bytes    
    System.Web.Mvc.dll!System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext controllerContext, System.Collections.Generic.IList<System.Web.Mvc.IActionFilter> filters, System.Web.Mvc.ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string,object> parameters) + 0x13a bytes    
    System.Web.Mvc.dll!System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext controllerContext, string actionName) + 0x15f bytes    
    System.Web.Mvc.dll!System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() + 0x9f bytes    
    System.Web.Mvc.dll!System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext) + 0x14f bytes    
    System.Web.Mvc.dll!System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest.AnonymousMethod__5() + 0x3e bytes    
    System.Web.Mvc.dll!System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.MakeVoidDelegate.AnonymousMethod__0() + 0x14 bytes    
    System.Web.Mvc.dll!System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest.AnonymousMethod__d() + 0x36 bytes    
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() + 0x1d5 bytes    
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep step, ref bool completedSynchronously) + 0x177 bytes    
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(System.Exception error) + 0x6f5 bytes    
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(System.Web.HttpContext context, System.AsyncCallback cb) + 0x85 bytes    
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(System.Web.Hosting.IIS7WorkerRequest wr, System.Web.HttpContext context) + 0x2b6 bytes    
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(System.IntPtr managedHttpContext, System.IntPtr nativeRequestContext, System.IntPtr moduleData, int flags) + 0x3bf bytes    
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(System.IntPtr managedHttpContext, System.IntPtr nativeRequestContext, System.IntPtr moduleData, int flags) + 0x22 bytes    
    [Native to Managed Transition]    
    [Managed to Native Transition]    
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationHelper(System.IntPtr managedHttpContext, System.IntPtr nativeRequestContext, System.IntPtr moduleData, int flags) + 0x4f4 bytes    
    System.Web.dll!System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.ProcessRequestNotification(System.IntPtr managedHttpContext, System.IntPtr nativeRequestContext, System.IntPtr moduleData, int flags) + 0x22 bytes
```

Is this issue related to incorrect Entity Framework contexts usage?
Thanks for help.

Comment: There is a lock in the Refresh method.  How it interacts with the rest of the threads isn't clear.  You best take this to Microsoft Support.  They'll at least need a stack trace of all threads.

Comment: When this happens, do you see BOTH deadlocked threads with the same stack trace? You said the majority of the deadlocked threads have this stack trace; can you post any others that you have seen? It is almost impossible to see how this is not a bug in TypeDescriptor, since the deadlock is occurring in a private static method which is locking internal data structures. But Hans is right; your best bet would be to contact Microsoft support.

Comment: Look at this link   https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/733827/deadlock-in-system-componentmodel-typedescriptor There are stacktraces of another threads.

Comment: What do you mean by: "thread become in join or sleep state during using EF context."  Make sure you aren't using the same EF context or attached objects on multiple threads:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.aspx
"The ObjectContext class is not thread safe. The integrity of data objects in an ObjectContext cannot be ensured in multithreaded scenarios."

Comment: Yes, EF context is not thread safe. But we keep it at HttpContext items (create EF context and put it to HttpContext items at the begining of request and dispose at the end ) which are thread static (thread safe in our case).

Comment: Do you use thread-static variables or HttpContext?

Comment: HttpContext which is thread-static

Comment: Actually, I think HttpContext is not thread-static. If it was it would be broken by asynchronous requests that are served by multiple threads. It uses CallContext. I suspect there is a false assumption you are using a single thread throughout the request pipeline going on here.

Comment: is it really a deadlock or just long waiting there? I had similar issue with long wait in MVC + EF. Can you check if your requests are in one AppDomain? Test it couple of times, while you don't have the lock, and tell us if there was even one request that was in different AppDomain than other.

Comment: Not entirely sure that this is related but the info might be of use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7176303/entity-framework-multiple-threads-lazy-load

Comment: Are your services stateless? HttpContext is an static variable, though it makes sense it's thread safe in the request context. Now, if you are spawning threads and EF contexts all over the place, then it might not be thread safe.

Can you provide some code?

Comment: Maybe Entity Framework is trying to use ports that are already in use. Try looping through a set of port numbers, so each connection will have his own port number.

Comment: Could you show some code?  Without it, it's impossible to say.  Starting with the code of `CompuTool.Presentation.Web.dll!CompuTool.Presentation.Web.Controllers.DesktopStateController.Set` would be helpful.  That and the *actual* exception that is being thrown would be helpful.  You've just given a stack trace, but no exception message or type.

Comment: @casperOne its a deadlock - there is no exception. I encountered the exact same scenario. See the MS Connect link + this EF issue I've opened: https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/2390

Comment: @bUKaneer that question is unrelated - that question deals with multiple threads accessing the same DbContext, here each request has its own context and the deadlock is in the TypeDescriptor class, called by the SqlCommand clone method's constructors setting of the DesignTimeVisible property.

Comment: I found the same deadlock here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15816602/deadlock-with-entity-framework-linq