# Deadlock with entity framework & LINQ

Tags: multithreading, linq, entity-framework, deadlock, typedescriptor

I have a asp.net/mvc 3/entity framework 4.1 web application which access a class library to get look up table data. When I hit the website for the first time and try to load two different pages simultaneously the app pool hangs. No dead lock or any activity in the database. I used windbg/vs2010 debugger to look for thread locks. Two threads are locking at `System.Component.TypeDescriptor`.

The execution gets stuck at `lookuptable.ToList` 
Code :

```
   Using transaction As New TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew, 
            New TransactionOptions() With 
              {.IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted})
            Using db As New Entity
              Dim lookuptable = From lk In db.LookUpTable Where lk.Id = pId Select lk
               returnValue = lookuptable.ToList
            End Using
    End Using
```

Parallel stack image:

[image]

Thanks for your help

Comment: Do you have any own locks, or do you share context between threads?

Comment: Why do you use a transaction for a simple read?

Comment: Besides any design problems (if it is a lookup you could cache it to avoid further reads), if you must (for any reason) share the context between threads, you should treat it like any other resource that must/cannot be executed in parallel. Also, complete the transaction you started by using transaction.Complete();

Comment: Have you tried it without the transaction?

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of the same deadlock in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9923459/deadlock-in-system-component-typedescriptor

Comment: @user2244625 See MS Connect bug here (vote it up + the recreate vote): https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/733827/deadlock-in-system-componentmodel-typedescriptor and EF issue here: https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/2390

Comment: @user2244625 did you solve the problem, any workaround?

Comment: what is `returnValue`?